# Encrypted Ubuntu won't boot: "Malformed Security Header"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, encryption, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu by following the guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019 and the installation worked very well for months.

However after applying Windows 10 Updates, Ubuntu will no longer prompt me for my password at boot, printing the following error message instead:

```
Malformed security header
Failed to read header: Invalid Parameter
Failed to load image: Invalid Parameter
start_image() returned Invalid Parameter, falling back [...]
Malformed security header
Failed to read header: Invalid Parameter
Failed to load image: Invalid Parameter
start_image() returned Invalid Parameter
```

I have 2 SSDs, one for Ubuntu and one for Windows, because I wanted to avoid exactly this scenario (one OS screwing up the other).
The Ubuntu SSD is called `nvme0n1`, it is also my boot disk and the partitions are as follows:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: XPG GAMMIX S50 Lite                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 35BB26D2-DCC3-4781-8C04-10DA391CFC12

Device            Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1     2048    4196351    4194304     2G Linux reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2  4196352    8390655    4194304     2G BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p3  8390656   12584959    4194304     2G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p5 12584960 2000409230 1987824271 947.9G Linux reserved
```

Both `nvme0n1p1` (`/boot`) and `nvme0n1p5` (`ubuntu-vg`) are encrypted.
I can open and mount both these encrypted volumes with `cryptsetup luksOpen` and see the files, at first glance everything seems to be in order.
I can also mount `nvme0n1p3` and look at the files.
When I try to mount `nvme0n1p2` however, this happens:

```
# mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/nvme0n1p2
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/nvme0n1p2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/nvme0n1p2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/nvme0n1p2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/nvme0n1p2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Using the tool **boot-repair** (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) I generated the following report: https://pastebin.com/1RueY6yF

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how I can fix this without reinstalling?